# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13 cannot be cast to CustomeClass

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am trying to learn AOP with Spring Framework, but there is one exception that keeps on getting invoked.

> Error :  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13 cannot be cast to com.controller.Triangle

**Shape.java**

```java
package com.controller;

public interface Shape {
    public void draw();
}
```

**Triangle.java**

```java
package com.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Triangle implements Shape
{
        public void draw()
        { 
              System.out.println("this draw method of triangle"),
        }
}
```

**myCustomAspect.java**

```java
    package com.AOP;

    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
    @Component
    @Aspect
    public class myCustomAspect {

        @Pointcut("execution(* *.draw())")
        private void pop(){}

        @Before("pop()")
        private void beforeMeth(){
            System.out.println("this is before draw"); }
    }
```

**inside main method**

```java
ApplicationContext  ssp = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/Spring.xml");
Shape tr=(Triangle)ssp.getBean("triangle");
tr.draw();
```

**Spring.XML**

```xml
    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
      <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xmlns:aop = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

     <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller,com.AOP"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

Please any one help.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for the information you provided. What you missed mentioning, though, is the Spring configuration. Please show _Spring.xml_ and also class `Shape`. Also learn what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and how it helps you to get good answers quickly here.

Comment: Hello Kriegaex, i have update all details you require, Please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the MCVE, now it was easy to recreate your problem and verify the fix. Just reading the code and not being able to run it did not make me spot the problem.

It is very simple: Your advice `beforeMeth()` must be public. Then everything works like a charm.

---

**Update:**

Okay, I think I know what is missing on your part. You are casting the created bean to `Triangle`, but that is not an interface but a class, thus it cannot be proxied by Spring AOP without further configuration. So you have two options here:

- Either you just change the code to `Shape tr = (Shape) appContext.getBean("triangle");` so as to cast to the interface that is automatically used by Spring in order to create the JDK dynamic proxy.
- Or you enable class proxying with CBLIB via `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>`. You can also use `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)` instead, of course.

Now here is a solution showing both approaches in parallel. You can switch by changing the value of `XML_CONFIG`.

BTW, I also corrected your package name `com.AOP` to `com.aop` (lower-case characters are the default for packages) and your Aspect name from `myCustomAspect` to `MyCustomAspect` (Java classes should start with an upper-case character). I also renamed `Spring.xml` to `spring.xml`. And in interfaces you do not need `public` for method declarations because all interface methods are by definition public. But all of this is just cosmetics, the real fix is the one above.

So here is your improved code:

```java
package com.controller;

public interface Shape {
  void draw();
}
```

```java
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Triangle implements Shape {
  public void draw() {
    System.out.println("this draw method of triangle");
  }
}
```

```java
package com.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class MyCustomAspect {
  @Pointcut("execution(* *.draw())")
  private void pop() {}

  @Before("pop()")
  public void beforeMeth() {
    System.out.println("this is before draw");
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.controller.Shape;
import com.controller.Triangle;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.controller", "com.aop" })
public class Application {
  private static final boolean XML_CONFIG = true;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext appContext =  XML_CONFIG
      ? new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring.xml")
      : new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
    Shape tr = (Triangle) appContext.getBean("triangle");
    tr.draw();
  }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
  ">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller,com.aop"></context:component-scan>
  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: It is still showing me the same error after converting method from private to public.

Comment: Then you have done something wrong, maybe forgotten to recompile or shown me code that is different from what you have locally.

Comment: Okay, I forgot to mention one more thing you did wrong. See my update.

Comment: Thank you soo much , now it got fixed after casting output of getBean() with Shape.