# Is it possible to intercept arguments of a method call and method inside which the method call is made : AOP

Tags: spring-boot, aop, aspect

I have a DAO that has some methods that make queries to a database using `org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. Few of this methods have certain method arguments and I would like to capture database queries made from these methods. I would like to write an AOP that would capture the SQL queries made from these methods along with the value of the argument. Below is one of the methods(that I need to capture) that makes jdbc query:
My DAO-

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getData(RequestParameters requestParameter, Map<String, Column> columnMap) {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    StringBuilder finalQuery = new StringBuilder();
    finalQuery.append(getDataQuery(requestParameter, columnMap, params));
    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(finalQuery.toString(), params);
```

I need an AOP solution that would capture `finalQuery` and `columnMap`.
Is that even possible in AOP. Do you have any other solutions?

I tried to write below aspect but I am able to only capture `finalQuery` but not `columnMap`

```
@Pointcut("withincode(public * com.abc.xyz..*.*(com.abc.xyz.RequestParameters, java.util.Map))")
private void anyGetDataMethodSignature() {
    // pointcut
}

@Pointcut("(call(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations.query*(..)) && within(com.abc.xyz.services..*.*))")
public void anyJDBCOperations() {
}

@Before("anyJDBCOperations() && anyGetDataMethodSignature()")
public void log(JoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
//......
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You really think you can just delete your old question which was put on hold and copy the content into a new question? When I was just trying to explain to you for the 3rd time in more detail which other information you should provide to make answering possible, suddenly the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50539711/1082681) was marked as "deleted by author". But I can still see it, there is still proof that you just refuse to play by the rules. Shame on you!

Comment: are you serious? I agree that my initial question was unclear but even after correcting my question (current version) it was still on hold. I think the question is clear to the audience I am targeting this question to. I deleted the previous question because it was on hold and would not reach the audience. do you want to play the same game? whats wrong with you? I am trying to find answers to my question so, if you are not going to help , please don't comment and misguide people.

Comment: I am serious, indeed. Look, you are new here, I understand. But there are rules on SO. It is forbidden to just delete and recreate a question on hold. Instead just improve the existing question. Someone else but you will eventually decide when a question has been improved enough to get re-opened. I have explained to you that I did not put it on hold but a vote of multiple users has. I also told you to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which you refused to do. The question still consists of incoherent code snippets. _(to be continued)_

Comment: Your target audience are Java developers with Spring AOP or AspectJ knowledge. I happen to be one of them. In order for AOP to work, you need a combination of Java + aspect code + configuration. The problem could be in any of them. subtle problems like wrong or misspelled package names in pointcuts, missing class annotations and many more could be the reason of your problem. So please provide full classes incl. package names plus Spring configuration. At the moment all we have is snippets - a good start, but not enough to answer the question, sorry. _(to be continued)_

Comment: Then especially in Spring you can use two types of AOP: proxy-based Spring AOP and full AspectJ via LTW (load-time weaving). Without any configuration I cannot see which one you are using. In the other question you also commented: _"There is not a reproducible code, I am asking for a solution here. I think anyone from java background would get what I am trying to ask."_ Both statements are false: Of course you can distill your problem into an MCVE. And understanding Java is not equivalent to understanding AOP. Obviously you have a Java background yourself, but also do not understand it, right?

Comment: The "call" and "withincode" PCD is not supported in Spring AOP, which means I am using AspectJ. I don't know why you need all the package details, the only thing I need to know is (in the method above getData()) how do I get arguments of method getData as well as arguments of method call (namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList()), which inside getData method. The AOP I have written captures arguments of namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList() and only staticPart(not the actual arguments) of getData.  Any solution would work for me here(Spring AOP or  AspectJ or any other way)

Comment: I know that `call()` and `withincode()` are unsupported by Spring AOP, thus the question! How can I know that you know? You are still spending so much time on explaining why you refuse to provide an MCVE, in the meantime you could have done that and your problem would have been solved days ago. I was really more than patient, but as of now I am out of here, and nobody else cares about your question, until now you only received ignorance and close votes. Still you think the world is against you and you know better how to ask questions. So why don't you get any answers? Go figure!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just in order to make you understand what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and how easy it is to provide one if you only want, I made one for you. Actually this was ***your job!*** Next time do it by yourself, please.

Your incoherent snippets do not tell me which classes to import, how variables like `namedParameterJdbcTemplate` are defined and initialised, how your Spring Boot is configured and many more things. So I had to make educated guesses and create dummy classes just so as to recreate your situation and test my own solution. Untested solutions are cr*p and so is a question forcing me to do that kind of guesswork in the first place.

What you want to implement is the **wormhole pattern**, see also my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12130175/1082681) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25075051/1082681), both in AspectJ native syntax. The one I prepared for you is in the annotation-based syntax I so dislike, but which you seem to prefer for whatever reason.

**Dummy helper classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class RequestParameters {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DummyJdbcTemplate {
  public List<Map<String, Object>> queryForList(String string, Map<String, Object> params) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Column {
  private String columnType;

  public Column(String columnType) {
    this.columnType = columnType;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Column[columnType=" + columnType + "]";
  }
}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Application {
  private DummyJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new DummyJdbcTemplate();

  public List<Map<String, Object>> getData(RequestParameters requestParameter, Map<String, Column> columnMap) {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    StringBuilder finalQuery = new StringBuilder();
    finalQuery.append(getDataQuery(requestParameter, columnMap, params));
    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(finalQuery.toString(), params);
  }

  public String getDataQuery(RequestParameters requestParameter, Map<String, Column> columnMap, Map<String, Object> params) {
    return "I am the final query";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Column> columnMap = new HashMap<>();
    columnMap.put("id", new Column("Long"));
    columnMap.put("name", new Column("VarChar"));
    columnMap.put("age", new Column("Int"));
    new Application().getData(new RequestParameters(), columnMap);
  }
}
```

**Aspect implementing wormhole pattern:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.Map;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import de.scrum_master.app.Column;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Pointcut(
    "execution(public * de.scrum_master.app..*(..)) && " +
    "args(de.scrum_master.app.RequestParameters, columns)"
  )
  private void anyGetDataMethodSignature(Map<String, Column> columns) {}

  @Pointcut(
    "call(* de.scrum_master.app.DummyJdbcTemplate.query*(..)) && " +
    "args(query, ..)"
  )
  private void anyJDBCOperations(String query) {}

  @Before(
    "anyJDBCOperations(query) &&" +
    "cflow(anyGetDataMethodSignature(columns))"
  )
  public void log(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Map<String, Column> columns, String query) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    System.out.println("  columns = " + columns);
    System.out.println("  query = " + query);
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
call(List de.scrum_master.app.DummyJdbcTemplate.queryForList(String, Map))
  columns = {name=Column[columnType=VarChar], id=Column[columnType=Long], age=Column[columnType=Int]}
  query = I am the final query
```

Now, Amit, what the heck was so difficult for you about providing a little example for your SO helpers' benefit, so they don't have to do your own job for free in their spare time? Just picking up and fixing your own MCVE would have been so much easier and definitely not asking too much of the experienced developer you seem to think you are. This sense of entitlement - "Developers here have nothing better to do than create a running example for themselves because I am too lazy." - I just don't get it. Who are you? A king?

Comment: Look, Amit, here is [another SO newbie with AOP problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50543787/1082681). He also did not provide an MCVE at first, then followed my advice and updated his question. Ten minutes later he got the solution from me. You wasted days and still did not do it. Why are you so stubborn? Are you not interested in solving your problems quickly? Be nice to other people, especially those you expect help from. There is a good chance they will also will be nice to you.